# Code not working with the if/else statements

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print("Select operation.")
print("1.Price of your luggage")
print("2.Exit")


# Take input from the user 
choice = input("Enter choice(1/2:")

if choice == '1':
    num1=(input("Enter wieght of your first  luggage " ))

if num1 <=15:
    print('Your first item is free')

elif num1 >=15:
    print('Your items will cost you money')

elif choice == '2':
    raise SystemExit()
```

This is the start of my assessment. Can I please have some help?

Comment: I removed the tag `class` as your code have nothing to do with it

Answer (score 2):

Your code had some indentation problems and also the user input is always of type `str` (string). You need to convert the weight to `int` before checking the if statement. You also should use `num1 > 15` without `=` because you have already used it in `num1 <= 15`. Here is the rectified code. As pointed out by [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) in the comments, your `elif` can simply be replaced by `else` because if the number is not less than equal to 15, it will be greater than 15.

```
print("Select operation.")
print("1.Price of your luggage")
print("2.Exit")

# Take input from the user 
choice = input("Enter choice(1/2:")
if choice == '1':
    num1 = int(input("Enter wieght of your first  luggage " ))
    if num1 <= 15:
        print('Your first item is free')
    else:
        print('Your items will cost you money')
elif choice == '2': 
    raise SystemExit()
```

---

> ```
> Select operation.
> 1.Price of your luggage
> 2.Exit
> Enter choice(1/2:1
> Enter wieght of your first  luggage 12
> Your first item is free
> ```

Comment: `elif num1 > 15` should just be `else`